# How to finish android apps

Tags: android-studio, build

As I finish coding at android studio and ready to post it, how can I finish it? 
I had already go to build and click make project, but nothing was happened. At event log wrote:"Gradle build finished in 11s 40ms"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try it on your app, connect it to your pc, enable USB debugging in the phone, download your phone drivers and then click the green triangle. If you want to publish it on google play, look that up.